# Beamer - Unnecessary space in bibliography

Tags: beamer, spacing, bibtex, bibliographies

I am using bibtex for referencing in beamer. My code is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},12pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber \hfill \vspace*{1mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First slide}
These are all references for bibliography.
\cite{Holden2003} ,\cite{Holden2005}, \cite{Holden2006}, \cite{Holden2007}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
\begin{small}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{small}
\end{frame}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 

\end{document}
```

The bibtex file is:

```
@article{Holden2005,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {02},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {50},
year = {2002}
}


@article{Holden2006,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {1},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Streamwise Slots}},
volume = {50},
year = {2002}
}

@article{Holden2007,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {European Congres on Computational Methohd in Applied Sciences and Engineering},
number = {September},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{The physics of shock wave/boundary layer interaction control: last lessons learned}},
year = {2002}
}

@article{Holden2009,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov, Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov and Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov and Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {50},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {50},
year = {2002}
}
```

Then the first slide only accommodates three items, whereas it can actually accommodate four items. This can be confirmed by removing the following part from the code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber \hfill \vspace*{1mm}
}
```

This shows that the issue comes from those lines. Because of this, my bibliography looks ugly and takes more pages. Any help/suggestion on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see if `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,t]{Reference}
\small
\bibliography{ref}
\end{frame}` helps.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Zarko, but that does not work.

Comment: Zako, I thank you for your patience to help me. The code I have pasted is a complete one, hence will be working in your computer too.

Comment: Zarko, the issue comes when using the bibtex file, thats why the code is given in bibtex format. The procedure to compile it is : "Save the bibtex code (the second set of codes) in the name -"ref.bib", put in the same folder of the main tex file and compile". Sorry for the complications, but I don't know how to make it simpler. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try with footnotesize instead of small. AFAIU, when you add one line on your slides (the footline), your bibliography gets too big and splits, so lowering the fontsize should fix it.

Comment: Sztruks, seems like that is the only way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't allow beamer to get into mischief by not putting `allowframebreaks` into your reference slide and everything will stay on one page.

Note: `\insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber` will give you inhomogeneous spacing around the backslash, I chnaged it to `\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},12pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber \hfill \vspace*{1mm}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Balle2002,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {02},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {3},
year = {2002}
}


@article{Holden2005,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {1},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Streamwise Slots}},
volume = {42},
year = {2005}
}

@article{Delery2000,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {European Congres on Computational Methohd in Applied Sciences and Engineering},
number = {September},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{The physics of shock wave/boundary layer interaction control: last lessons learned}},
year = {2000}
}

@article{Bountin2013,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov, Timur and Maslov, Anatoly and Novikov, Andrey and Egorov, Ivan and Fedorov, Alexander and Utyuzhnikov, Sergey},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {5},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {51},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First slide}
These are all references for bibliography.
\cite{Balle2002} ,\cite{Holden2005}, \cite{Delery2000}, \cite{Bountin2013}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Reference}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

If there are more references in the real document and the `allowframebreaks` option should be preserved, slightly reducing the font size will also get the first 4 entries on one page.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},12pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber \hfill \vspace*{1mm}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Balle2002,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {02},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {3},
year = {2002}
}


@article{Holden2005,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {1},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Streamwise Slots}},
volume = {42},
year = {2005}
}

@article{Delery2000,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov},
journal = {European Congres on Computational Methohd in Applied Sciences and Engineering},
number = {September},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{The physics of shock wave/boundary layer interaction control: last lessons learned}},
year = {2000}
}

@article{Bountin2013,
author = {Bountin, Dmitry and Chimitov, Timur and Maslov, Anatoly and Novikov, Andrey and Egorov, Ivan and Fedorov, Alexander and Utyuzhnikov, Sergey},
journal = {Journal of Aircraft},
number = {5},
pages = {1203--1210},
title = {{Separated Shock Boundary-Layer Interaction Control Using Stream}},
volume = {51},
year = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography item}{size=\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First slide}
These are all references for bibliography.
\cite{Balle2002} ,\cite{Holden2005}, \cite{Delery2000}, \cite{Bountin2013}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not seem like possible, because I have a lot of references, and manually splitting them into frames would be extremely difficult.  Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Ashok Please see my edit